# CI recommendation

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm currently looking for a CI which could integrated with bitbucket. I find a list of CIs here http://wiki.ros.org/CIs but an objective comparison is not provided. Could anyone give me some advice about the pros and cons of each CI?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273190/ci-recommendation/) by [lt101018](https://answers.ros.org/users/32273/lt101018/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2017-10-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think there are enough people around here that have enough experience in all the listed CI solutions to give an objective answer to your question. Instead, use the following algorithm

```
bad_solutions = set()
while True:
    selected = pick_random_CI_solution_for_bitbucket(do_not_use=bad_solutions)
    if give_quick_test(selected) == "OK":
        continue_using_it_and_be_happy_until_it_breaks()
        bad_solutions.add(selected)
```

Basically, just pick one, and try it. If it works, keep it, else find a different one.

---

Originally posted by [Alberth](https://answers.ros.org/users/32151/alberth/) with karma: 91 on 2017-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lt101018](https://answers.ros.org/users/32273/lt101018/) on 2017-10-18**:
Thank you I will try

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just added an [objective comparison table](http://wiki.ros.org/CIs#Objective_Comparison) (very sparse yet). Admittedly I'm an author-maintainer of one of those tools, and haven't tried all of them so I can't fill all in. Feel free to fill in cells, add columns etc.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2017-12-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1